# Why does audio playback seem to depend on GPU memory?

Tags: pitft, gpu, audio-playback, memory-split

I encountered a really odd behaviour with my Raspberry Pi B+, running a slightly modified version of Raspbian with a [PiTFT screen from Adafruit](https://www.adafruit.com/products/1601). Because the screen cannot access the GPU I dialed down the GPU memory as low as it would go during installation (4 MB I think?).

I wanted to use the system as a portable music player, but I found the audio playback was extremely poor (constant skipping). I tried changing the GPU memory split to 32 MB, and all of a sudden the playback was completely smooth.

I thought that the GPU was primarily used for handling calculations performed while rendering 3D graphics. Why would it affect audio playback this noticeably?

Comment: What audio player did you use?

Comment: cmus, moc, and a few others, but the behaviour was consistent across different programs.

Comment: Did you try omxplayer?

Comment: With `mpg321` and my GPU memory set to 0 I have perfect playback.

Comment: The last I read the [minimum settable GPU memory was 16MB](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt.md) - I think if you set it lower than that it's still rounded up to 16MB.

Comment: Yeah, that was what I thought. Actually though, after reading that link, I wonder if it isnt this:
  
  
`Setting gpu_mem to low values may automatically disable certain firmware features, as there are some things the GPU simply can't do with too little memory. So if a certain feature you're trying to use isn't working, try setting a larger GPU memory split.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Raspberry Pi sound system is controlled by the GPU, both for HDMI and analog audio output. An interesting detail are the noise shaping algorithms running on the GPU for analog output. Quite a bit of engineering went into them, seeing that the analog audio hardware itself is quite poor.

Sources:

["Analogue Audio testing" raspberrypi.org](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=136445) 
["Analogue Audio redux" raspberrypi.org](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=195178)